# create-react-app does not work in my ubuntu vagrant machine

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, create-react-app

I have been trying this for several houses now to install and run react in my vagrant ubuntu (14) box.

I have followed instructions from the following page (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/getting-started)

npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start

and every time I run
yarn start I get the following error message

yarn run v1.15.2
error Could not write file "/var/www/html/my-app/yarn-error.log": "EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/html/my-app/yarn-error.log'"
error An unexpected error occurred: "EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/home/vagrant/.config/yarn/link'".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

I have tried to

1. change the permission to +x but the problem does not seem to go away.
2. uninstall create-react from npm and use only yarn's create-react.

I am sure people are running react on ubuntu in vagrant machine. What am I missing here?